# How to able and disable button on clicking on checkbox in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

My template:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" >
<button class="pull-left" (click)='openup()' [Disabled]='button'>Delete</button>
```

My ts:

```
button:any = false;
openup(){
     this.button = false;
  }
```

I followed the above process, but it's not working for me.

Can anyone please suggest me help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are setting a variable, that is already false, to false again, so nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

ts :

```
toggleButton: boolean = false;
```

template:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" 
  (click)='toggleButton = !toggleButton' >
<button class="pull-left"  [disabled]='toggleButton'>Delete</button>
```